# Select the parent div only if it has id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the first parent `div` that has `id` attribute.

The selectors is `'div .img'` and it could be inside any nested div

```
<div id='div1'>

 <div id='div2'> first nested parent div

       <div>second div
            <img class='img' src='test.jpg'/> 
       </div>   

 </div>

 <div>  //this div has no id
      <div>another div
           <img class='img' src='cookie.jpg'/> 
      </div>   
 <div>

</div>
```

The selector

```
$('div.img')
```

should output

```
div2 
div1

div2 shows first becasue div2 has id attribute and it is the parent of the test.img
div1 shows next becasue cookie is the second image and the first parent div that has div1 id
```

I have tried

```
if($('div .img').find('.img').closest('div').attr('id')){
   console.log($('div.img').closest('div').attr('id'))
}
```

but it doesn't work. Are there anyways to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: There's no `div` with class `img` in your code...

Comment: `div.img` won't match anything in your example, it seems `div .img` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var IamadivparentandhaveanId=$('div').find('img').closest('div[id]');
```

OR using the class:

```
$('div').find('img.img').closest('div[id]');
```

or

```
$('.img').closest('div[id]');
```

EDIT per comment to clarify use to ONLY find them once:

```
$('img.img').each(function(){
   $(this).closest('div[id]');
});// or use .filter if that is perferred
```

Comment: `closest()` will only return the *first* match, though.

Comment: You have a point; hmm. Looking at his expected output is what led me to believe that `parents()` was the required. Clarification would be useful.

Comment: yes, depends on the use and if he wants to manipulate it inside, like the .each or return the parents list filtered...hard to tell fully.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var divsWithIDs = $('img.img').parents('div[id]').get();
console.log(divsWithIDs);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5BcGL/).

This approach looks for the `img.img` element, then looks through the parents of those images to find those `div` elements that have an `id` attribute. The `get()` method converts the selection to an array.

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var $divsWithIds = $('img.img').closest('div[id]');
```

This is the same as the answer by @David Thomas, except using `closest` instead of `parents`. It selects all "img" elements with the ".img" class, and then gets the closest parent for each one.

In the following situation, using `parents()` will include both "div1" and "div2", whereas using `closest()` will return only 'div2':

```
<div id='div1'>
    <div id='div2'>
       <div>
            <img id="img1" class='img' src='test.jpg'/> 
       </div>   
    </div>
</div>

 <div>
       <img id="img2" class='img' src='cookie.jpg'/> 
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery each to iterate over the parents.

```
$('div img').each(function (a, b) {
    var x = $(b).parent();
    while (x && !x.attr('id')) {
        x = x.parent();
    }
    console.log(x.attr('id'));
});
```